# Voice to text using nodeJS

Tags: open-source, node.js, speech-recognition

I need a nodeJS package to convert voice to text.

It should support all browsers, be open source and free for enterprise use.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Cloud Speech: Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech) which is the most powerful package for these kind of stuff

Comment: 1)Is it free for commercial use?
2) Does all the files save in the local system or in Google cloud?